# set conditions to access play framework 2 actions

Tags: playframework-2.0

I want to set a rule for accessing a route to some users that I created.
My user model is :

```
public class User extends Model{

    public String firstName;

    @Required
    public String lastName;

    @Required
    public String password;

    @Required
    public boolean labAccess;

    public boolean labAccess() {
       return labAccess;
    }
}
```

After users log in to the main page, I have a route link to the "Laboratory page".
I want to set a rule for users: if the **labAccess** of User is true he/she can click the route to see the laboratory page.

My controller action is like this :

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result login() {
        return ok(login.render(form(Login.class)));
    }

    public static Result laboratory() {
        return ok(laboratoryPage.render("hello. welcome to lab));
    }
}
```

How to set this rule? Do I need to save something in session or set some constraint on actions in my Application class?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use Action Composition. Checkout the [official documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaActionsComposition)!

Comment: thanks brother! but i saw that doc, then came to this forum please write an example if possible, not resource